# 404 error when renaming (changing) store-view code in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

This error has been eating my head since 2 days! I have searched the entire internet!

**Scene:**
I have a Magento store (1.7.0.2) with 1 website, 1 store and 2 storeviews.

First store view code is `my_uk_en`

Second store view code is `my_uk_ru`

Everything works fine until I rename (change) the StoreView to something else.

I renamed the storeview code to `my_cz_en`, and frontend gives `404 error`.

I have checked my `index.php` and `.htaccess` files, there is no store called explicitly.

I tried running the new store forecefully by using the following in index.php

```
$mageRunCode = "my_cz_en";
$mageRunType = "store";
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

But still same `404`!
I also ran a search on my entire database with the old storeview code (**my_uk_en**) and there was no matches.

The storeview is assigned to a **CMS homepage** as well. The setting `Add Store Code to URL` is disabled.

Inspite of all these I don't understand why I am getting `404 error`.

Comment: Standard question, but I need to get it out of the way. Did you clear the cache and rebuilt your indexes?

Comment: Of course I did :P I am a Mage dev. Cache cleaned and disabled. Reindexed multiple times. Still no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the culprit! There was this phtml file which had

```
Mage::app()->getStore('my_uk_en')
```

in it. I changed it to my new storeview code and it worked. So if anyone gets this error in future, do run a full search on your entire codebase for the old storeview code. Thanks.